# mysql emerge error upon compiling.. is that normal?

Tags: mysql, gentoo, federated

```
* configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-plugindir, --without-plugin-example, --without-plugin-ibmdb2i, --without-plugin-ndbcluster, --witho$ 
* configure: WARNING:$ unrecognized options: --with-plugindir, --without-plugin-example, --without-plugin-ibmdb2i, --without-plugin-ndbcluster, --with$
```

I was trying to emerge mysql 5.1 with all the db engines possible and i got some errors in compile. This is wierd because it should of been tested by the gentoo team before publish

I'm really interested into using the federated engine so the commands i've inputed and files i've modified were:

```
gentoo # cat /etc/portage/package.use 
dev-db/mysql ~x86 extraengine 


gentoo # cat /etc/portage/package.keywords 
=dev-db/mysql-5.1.46 
=virtual/mysql-5.1 

ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="~x86" emerge -p mysql 

gentoo # emerge -av mysql 
[ebuild R ] dev-db/mysql-5.1.46 USE="community extraengine perl ssl -big-tables -cluster -debug -embedded -latin1 -max-idx-128 -minimal -pbxt -profiling (-selinux) -static -test -xtradb" 0 kB
```

After install, when i did show engines in mysql the same engines were added as before, no extra engines were enabled... I have the full log saved if that helps,

I've been strugling for some days now into trying to acomplish this and i couldn't

---

Update:

I think it compiled as a plugin, but the plugin option did gave an error upon compiling

```
100717 21:48:40 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'federated=ON' 
100717 21:48:40 [ERROR] Aborting Upon compiling: 
checking whether to use Federated Storage Engine... plugin 
checking whether to use Memory Storage Engine... yes ---   
   usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_federated.so.0.0.0 usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_innodb_plugin.so.0.0.0
```

Comment: The flag is --federated, not --federated=ON. It also requires MySQL compiled with extraengine flag.

Answer (score 0):

This MySQL release isn't stable yet in Gentoo Portage, so although in may be tested by the Gentoo team to verify the ebuild is correct before it was published, it could be unstable.

Did you enable the federated storage engine in your `my.cnf`?

```
[mysqld]
federated=ON
```